# How to implement second level menu for bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, theming, navigation, bootstrap-theme

i am using bootstrap theme for my drupal site, it has menus like menu 1 & menu 2 in header region. when i click on menu 1 it has to display it's sub menus like sub menu 1, sub menu 2, submenu3 ... for this requirement, i used **menu block** module. but it does not slove my problem.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use menu block.
Just check the checkbox "Show as expanded".